# AlarmManager shifts time by 12 hours

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm trying to create periodical notifications.
So, I created a function to reschedule new notification time:

```
private void rescheduleNotification(Context context) {
    long nextNotifTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    // Schedule next notification in 15 minutes
    nextNotifTime += 15 * 60 * 1000;

    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(nextNotifTime);
    // It's an old version with the same result
    //calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
    this.logEvent("      Next notification time is: " + sdf.format(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, WordsBcReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        manager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nextNotifTime, pendingIntent);
    } else {
        manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nextNotifTime, pendingIntent);
    }
    this.logEvent("   Set next notification time: " + sdf.format(nextNotifTime));
}
```

Sometimes it runs correctly, but sometimes notification time shifts by exactly 12 hours.

I added special function to log all time manipulations, so the log contains:

```
29/12/17 11:30:36:    Next notification time is: 29/12/17 12:00:36
29/12/17 11:30:36:    Set next notification time: 29/12/17 12:00:36
```

seems OK, but *adb shell dumpsys alarm* says:

```
type=0 whenElapsed=+11h34m13s906ms when=2017-12-30 00:00:36
```

I tried to use Calendar (I to exclude some periods later), but result was the same.
Can't find the problem...

Comment: Change your date formatter to use "dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss a" if it prints 12 AM then you are getting the correct time, 12 AM is represented as 00:00 in 24 hours format

Comment: I've changed it:    
  
`30/12/17 08:50:31:       Next notification time is: 30/12/17 09:05:31 AM
30/12/17 08:50:31:    Set next notification time: 30/12/17 09:05:31 AM`  
  
So, seems it's OK, but again:    
  
`type=0 whenElapsed=+8h15m0s238ms when=2017-12-30 21:05:31`